# How to make button show up after clicking hidden button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, show-hide

I am making a page using html, css and jquery. I want a button to be visible after clicking a button that has been hidden before using .hide(); function. Lots of buttons are hidden when the page is loaded, so when I click 1 button, other buttons from .hide become .show on click. 
But I want to make another button become .show after clicking another button that's .show, that has been clicked on after being hidden. 
When I try to implement it, all the buttons just show up on the page and it becomes chaos.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Speedtrapknapp").hide();
    $("#Politihovedknapp").hide();
    $("#Accidentknapp").hide();
    $("#Trafficjamknapp").hide();
    $("#visibletrap").hide();
    $("#hiddentrap").hide();
    $("#smallBtn").hide();
    $("#mediumBtn").hide();
    $("#bigBtn").hide();
    $("#vehicleinspectBtn").hide();
    $("#alcoholBtn").hide();
    $("#speedBtn").hide();
    $("#tagBtn1").hide();

    $("#Speedtrap1").click(function () {
        $("#visibletrap").show();
        $("#hiddentrap").show();
        $("#Speedtrapknapp").show();
        $("#Politihovedknapp").hide();
        $("#Accidentknapp").hide();
        $("#Trafficjamknapp").hide();
        $("#smallBtn").hide();
        $("#mediumBtn").hide();
        $("#bigBtn").hide();
        $("#vehicleinspectBtn").hide();
        $("#alcoholBtn").hide();
        $("#speedBtn").hide();
        $("tagBtn1").hide();

    });

    $("#Policecontrol1").click(function () {
        $("#alcoholBtn").show();
        $("#vehicleinspectBtn").show();
        $("#SpeedBtn").show();
        $("#Speedtrapknapp").hide();
        $("#Politihovedknapp").show();
        $("#Accidentknapp").hide();
        $("#Trafficjamknapp").hide();
        $("#visibletrap").hide();
        $("#hiddentrap").hide();
        $("#smallBtn").hide();
        $("#mediumBtn").hide();
        $("#bigBtn").hide();
        $("#speedBtn").show();
        $("tagBtn1").hide();
    });

    $("#TrafficJam1").click(function () {

        $("#Speedtrapknapp").hide();
        $("#Politihovedknapp").hide();
        $("#Accidentknapp").hide();
        $("#Trafficjamknapp").show();
        $("#visibletrap").hide();
        $("#hiddentrap").hide();
        $("#smallBtn").show();
        $("#mediumBtn").show();
        $("#bigBtn").show();
        $("#vehicleinspectBtn").hide();
        $("#alcoholBtn").hide();
        $("#speedBtn").hide();
        $("tagBtn1").hide();
    });

    $("#Accident1").click(function () {

        $("#Speedtrapknapp").hide();
        $("#Politihovedknapp").hide();
        $("#Accidentknapp").show();
        $("#Trafficjamknapp").hide();
        $("#visibletrap").hide();
        $("#hiddentrap").hide();
        $("#smallBtn").show();
        $("#mediumBtn").show();
        $("#bigBtn").show();
        $("#vehicleinspectBtn").hide();
        $("#alcoholBtn").hide();
        $("#speedBtn").hide();
        $("tagBtn1").hide();
    });

    $("#Clear1").click(function () {

        $("#Speedtrapknapp").hide();
        $("#Politihovedknapp").hide();
        $("#Accidentknapp").hide();
        $("#Trafficjamknapp").hide();
        $("#visibletrap").hide();
        $("#hiddentrap").hide();
        $("#smallBtn").hide();
        $("#mediumBtn").hide();
        $("#bigBtn").hide();
        $("#vehicleinspectBtn").hide();
        $("#alcoholBtn").hide();
        $("#speedBtn").hide();
        $("tagBtn1").hide();
    });

});
```

I have tried with

```
$("smallBtn").click()
("tagBtn1").show;
```

but it doesn't work. I want to make the "tagBtn1" appear after pressing "smallBtn", "mediumBtn" osv.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You should really look in to using classes to group your elements where needed.

Comment: Can you tell me here `smallBtn` and `tagBtn1` are ID's or Classes of these elements??

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZeeshan, just a wild guess: ALL ID'S!

Comment: yes, those are all ID's

Comment: "WHen I try to implement it, all the buttons just show up on the page and it becomes chaos." Does this mean the buttons are NEVER hidden, not even when the page is first loaded?

Comment: `$("somestring").hide()` is only valid jQuery if `somestring` is a tag. Perhaps you meant `$("#tagBtn1").hide();` and   `$("#tagBtn1").show();`

Comment: Create a jsfiddle so we can see the HTML too

Answer (score 1):

use # sign before selecting an element with ID in jQuery and an anonymous function must be pass in parenthesis (i.e click(function(){})) i.e:

```
$("#smallBtn").click(function(){
  ("#tagBtn1").show();
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work, I have tried that. When I Write that code, suddenly all the buttons appear when the page is loaded